# Can I programmatically move the steps of a mat-horizontal-stepper in Angular / Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a question regards Angular Material (with Angular 4+). Say in my component template I add a `<mat-horizontal-stepper>` component, and within each step `<mat-step>` I have stepper buttons to navigate the component. Like so...

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
  <mat-step>
    Step 1
    <button mat-button matStepperPrevious type="button">Back</button>
    <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    Step 2
    <button mat-button matStepperPrevious type="button">Back</button>
    <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    Step 3
    <button mat-button matStepperPrevious type="button">Back</button>
    <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Now I am wondering if it is possible to remove the buttons out of each step and have them elsewhere in the `<mat-horizontal-stepper>` in a static position or even outside the `<mat-horizontal-stepper>` and I can navigate backwards and forwards using code within my component typescript file. To give an idea, I would like my HTML be something like this

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
    <mat-step>
        Step 1
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
        Step 2
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
        Step 3
    </mat-step>
    <!-- one option -->
    <div>
       <button mat-button matStepperPrevious type="button">Back</button>
       <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
    </div>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>

<!-- second option -->
<div>
   <button (click)="goBack()" type="button">Back</button>
   <button (click)="goForward()" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to jump to a specific stepper by using `selectedIndex` property of the `MatStepper`. Also,  `MatStepper` exposes public methods `next()` and `previous()`. You can use them to move back and forth.

**In your template:**

Add an id to your stepper e.g. `#stepper`. Then in your `goBack()` and `goForward()` methods, pass the stepper id:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
    <!-- Steps -->
</mat-horizontal-stepper>    
<!-- second option -->
<div>
   <button (click)="goBack(stepper)" type="button">Back</button>
   <button (click)="goForward(stepper)" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

**.. and in your typescript:**

```
import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material/stepper';

goBack(stepper: MatStepper){
    stepper.previous();
}

goForward(stepper: MatStepper){
    stepper.next();
}
```

Link to [**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-beta-ybbnhe?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

---

You can also use `ViewChild` to get a reference to the stepper component in your TypeScript as shown below:

```
@ViewChild('stepper') private myStepper: MatStepper;

goBack(){
    this.myStepper.previous();
}

goForward(){
    this.myStepper.next();
}
```

In this case, you don't have to pass the stepper reference in the method in your component's html. Link to [**Demo with ViewChild**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-beta-vp7whl?file=app/app.component.html)

---

You can enable/disable the `Back` and `Next` buttons by using the following:

```
<button (click)="goBack(stepper)" type="button" 
        [disabled]="stepper.selectedIndex === 0">Back</button>
<button (click)="goForward(stepper)" type="button" 
        [disabled]="stepper.selectedIndex === stepper._steps.length-1">Next</button>
```

Comment: I was just looking at `ViewChild` and seeing how I could reference the Stepper -  but you have beaten me to it! Love the fact you added the disable / enable functionality too! Have some points!

Comment: `ViewChild` is also a good option to get the stepper. But I would prefer passing an id. I have also added `ViewChild` solution in the demo \o/

Comment: Hi Faisal thanks for such a great answer ,one more help, instead of passing a form to mat-step can we pass angular components and then depending upon that component being valid can I traverse to the next mat-step, how that can be achieved, thankyou

Comment: Nice solution. But how could we restrict the scrolling area to just the content of the stepper and not the actual header. If you add heaps of content, then the header will scroll out of sight. Since the header gives an indication of where the user is in some process, then it's important that the header is visible regardless of the amount of content in each step.

Comment: Here the completed steps icons is set to "EDIT" and the current steps icon is set to "NUMBER" can I have the completed steps icon as "DONE(tick)" and when back button pressed the completed step icon changed to "Edit"....EX: assume I completed step 2 and clicked on next button now the step 2's icon showing as "EDIT icon(pen symbol)" and now I am in step 3 which shows "Number" as icon....What I want to do is the When next btn clicked from step 2 the icon should be "DONE" and 3rd step icon should be "Number",if I clicked back btn of 3rd step the icon of 3rd step should be "DONE" 2nd is "EDIT".

Comment: Any clue how to get this working when using ng-if on mat-horizontal-stepper?

Comment: On having the `[linear]="true"` attribute on my stepper, I can't programmatically call the next one. Is there a reason why?

Comment: If you are using Angular 8, and using @ViewChild, you should use _static: false_

`@ViewChild('stepper', {static: false}) private myStepper: MatStepper;`

Per Angular, this value will default to _false_ in Angular 9+
[link](https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration)

Comment: (goBack(){
    this.myStepper.previous();
}
)

What about itsunit test? Can we have that too?

Comment: This solution also works if the stepper is in a mat-dialog-content in which case the matStepperNext doesn't work.

Answer (score 48):

In addition to @[Faisal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1791913/faisal)'s answer, this is my take on making the MatStepper jump without needing to pass the stepper in the arguments.

This is helpful when you need more flexibility in manipulating the stepper e.g. from a `Service` or something else.

HTML:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="6px">
  <button (click)="move(0)">1st</button>
  <button (click)="move(1)">2nd</button>
  <button (click)="move(2)">3rd</button>
  <button (click)="move(3)">4th</button>
</div>
```

TS File:

```
move(index: number) {
    this.stepper.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

Here's the **[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-matstepper-move).**

Comment: Is it possible when using mat-horizontal-stepper `linear="true"`?

Comment: no, see other answers with .next()

Answer (score 34):

If you **want to navigate programmatically** to next step and if you are **using a linear stepper**, follow the below steps:

- Create a `stepper` like this:   `<mat-horizontal-stepper linear #matHorizontalStepper>`
- Define `mat-step` like this: `<mat-step [completed]="isThisStepDone">`
- From inside `mat-step` create a button to go to next step like this:   `<button  (click)="next(matHorizontalStepper)">NEXT STEP</button>`
- In `.ts` file declare a `MatStepper` reference named *stepper* :
  `@ViewChild('matHorizontalStepper') stepper: MatStepper;`
- Also, within `.ts` file initialize `isThisStepDone` as **false** : `isThisStepDone: boolean = false;`
- Then write method for *NEXT STEP* button named `next()`:

  ```
   submit(stepper: MatStepper) {
    this.isThisStepDone = true;
    setTimeout(() => {           // or do some API calls/ Async events
     stepper.next();
    }, 1);
   }
  ```

NOTE: The **async part (`setTimeout()`) is required** due to state propagation via isThisStepDone.

Comment: The async part (`setTimeout()`) is required due to state propagation via `isThisStepDone`.

Comment: Thnks bruh, this was the one I was looking for.. For linear stepper.

Comment: The method in your example code is named wrong. Should be "next", not "submit".

Comment: Is there a way to use the completed state of the current step to disable/enable the button?

Answer (score 6):

If you are inside of child components, you can inject the stepper.

```
MyMainPageWithStepper.html (simplified)

<mat-horizontal-stepper>
  <mat-step label="Upload">
    <my-component></my-component>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>

MyComponent.ts

constructor(private readonly _stepper: CdkStepper}{}

someFunction(): void {
   this._stepper.next();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do it by specifying the actual index of the stepper using selectedIndex.

stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rvy2s?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.ts

HTML:

```
<div class="fab-nav-container">
   <mat-vertical-stepper linear="false" #stepper>
       <mat-step *ngFor="let step of stepNodes; let i = index">
           <ng-template matStepLabel>
               <p> {{step.title}} </p>
           </ng-template>
       </mat-step>
   </mat-vertical-stepper>
</div>

<div class="button-container">
   <div class="button-grp">
      <button mat-stroked-button (click)="clickButton(1, stepper)">1</button>
      <button mat-stroked-button (click)="clickButton(2, stepper)">2</button>
      <button mat-stroked-button (click)="clickButton(3, stepper)">3</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatVerticalStepper } from '@angular/material';
import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material';
export interface INodes {
    title: string;
    seq: number;
    flowId: string;
}
/**
 * @title Stepper overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'stepper-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'stepper-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['stepper-overview-example.scss'],
})
export class StepperOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatVerticalStepper) vert_stepper: MatVerticalStepper;
  @ViewChild('stepper') private myStepper: MatStepper;

  stepNodes: INodes[] = [
    { title: 'Request Submission', seq: 1, flowId: 'xasd12'}, 
    { title: 'Department Approval', seq: 2, flowId: 'erda23'}, 
    { title: 'Requestor Confirmation', seq: 3, flowId: 'fsyq51'}, 
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.vert_stepper._getIndicatorType = () => 'number';
  }
  clickButton(index: number, stepper: MatStepper) {
      stepper.selectedIndex = index - 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am just useing `@ViewChild('stepper') private myStepper: MatStepper;` and than `this.matStepper.next();` in my function. Working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The solution I implemented allows previous step validations (it fills the validation dots):

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
        if(this.isDone) {
          this.stepper.selectedIndex = 0;
          this.stepper.linear = false;
    
          // remove the validation // which makes the next call to the next method validate the step. warning => the validation should be readded.
          this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
            email: ['',],
            password:['',]
          });
    
          this.stepper.next();
          
          this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
            pricingYear: ['',],
            pricingMontly: ['',],
          });
          this.stepper.next();
    
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.stepper.linear = true;
         });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a ViewChild on MatStepper

in HTML file:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper class="transactions-stepper">
    <mat-step></mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

and defined next and previous method on ts file

in TS file:

```
@ViewChild('stepper') private stepper: MatStepper;

nextStep(): void {
   this.stepper.next();
}

previousStep(): void {
   this.stepper.previous();
}
```

also you can pass viewChild for stepper by input on component for
next or previous on your child components

like:

```
<transactions-list #transactionsList [stepper]="stepper"></transactions-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution if you want to know what step is currently selected and to only move to another step if the user is not there.

Set an id to the mat-step

```
<mat-stepper #stepper>
 <mat-step id='product'></mat-step>
 <mat-step id='date'></mat-step>
 <mat-step id='info'></mat-step>
</mat-stepper>
```

Now in the component if we want to go to the "date" step we can do something like this:

```
  @ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;
  goToDate() {
   const firstStepId = this.stepper.steps?.first?.content?.elementRef?.nativeElement?.parentElement?.id;
      if (firstStepId === 'product' && this.stepper.selectedIndex === 0) {
        this.stepper.next();
      }
  }
```