# SelectedIndex of stepper not getting updated on click of button in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I click the Update Status button specified, the stepper does not get updated to the provided index.

html file:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<h2>Connection Status</h2>
<button class="btn btn-primary waves-light" mdbWavesEffect (click)=openDialog()>Update Status</button>
<p>
   <mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper>
      <mat-step label="Connection Request Sent"></mat-step>
      <mat-step label="Connection Response Received"></mat-step>
      <mat-step label="Connection Established"></mat-step>
      <mat-step label="Done"></mat-step>
   </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</p>
```

ts file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { MatHorizontalStepper } from "@angular/material/stepper";

@Component({
selector: "app-stepper-test",
templateUrl: "./stepper-test.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./stepper-test.component.scss"]
})
 export class StepperTestComponent implements OnInit {@
    ViewChild(MatHorizontalStepper, {
        static: false
    })
    stepper: MatHorizontalStepper;
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}
    openDialog() {
        this.stepper.selectedIndex = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I programmatically move the steps of a mat-horizontal-stepper in Angular / Angular Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469233/can-i-programmatically-move-the-steps-of-a-mat-horizontal-stepper-in-angular-a)

Comment: What error are you getting? Guide me through it and what exactly you want to do. Because, i have run it on my `ng project`, it is updating when i click the button `updateStatus`.

Comment: As you use `linear` stepper, [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50064564/4880379). It is one of the answers for the question linked in my previous comment.